# Pandas style `.render()` - Different values before and after display

Tags: python, html, pandas, pandas-styles

I'm trying to display several pandas dataframes horizontally in a Jupyter notebook, but am running into a situation where the styler's HTML is not formatted correctly.

I have the following code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML

def display_multi_table(table_list, with_display):
    if with_display:
      for t in table_list: display(t)
    return HTML(
        '<table><tr style="background-color:white;">' + 
        ''.join(['<td style="height:300px;width:300px">' + table.render() + '</td>' for table in table_list]) +
        '</tr></table>'
    )

d = dict([(f"column_{i}", np.random.rand(5)) for i in range(3)])
tables = [pd.DataFrame(d).style.set_caption("Title") for i in range(3)]
```

The following call:

```
display_multi_table(tables, False)
```

Results in this output: [image]

The following call:

```
display_multi_table(tables, True)
```

Results in this output:[image]

My goal: Achieve the output at the bottom of the second screenshot without having to call `display`.

Things I've tried/checked:

- If I don't style the pandas dataframe, and use simply call `.to_html()` on the dataframe instead of calling `.render()` on the styler, this issue does not exist. However, I need this to work on a style dataframe.
- I've confirmed that the value returned by `table.render()` before and after calling `display` is indeed different.

Answer (score 4):

Try passing your html into display, rather than calling display() on each table individually:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML

def display_multi_table(table_list, with_display):
    html = HTML(
        '<table><tr style="background-color:white;">' + 
        ''.join(['<td style="height:300px;width:300px">' + table.render() + '</td>' for table in table_list]) +
        '</tr></table>'
    )
    if with_display:
        display(html)
    return html
```

Note that if you call `display_multi_table(tables, True)` at the end of a jupyter cell, without setting it equal to anything, it will effectively display the tables twice – once from `display(html)`, and once from the return value of your function (`return html`). If that is undesired behavior, then just set the function call equal to a variable, (`html = display_multi_table(tables, True)`), or set `with_display` to `False`.

Comment: Tried a bunch of different variations around returning, not returning, displaying, but nothing worked. It might indeed be related to a pacakge or kernel version of some sort (as @Keldorn pointed out below), but it's hard to pinpoint the exact root cause.

Comment: I fail to see what the issue is. The output you gave above matches the code you wrote

Comment: `display()` is like using `print()`. It's separate from a function return value, but it will show you what you give it when it's run. You can make a function that both does `print('hello world')` and does `return 'hello world'`. My point was if you want the stuff from `display()` to be formatted, then you could pass HTML to `display()` directly.

Comment: I executed the following code and found that the output it prints is False. Any idea why that would happen?
```
  h1 = table_list[0].render()

  for t in table_list:
    display(t)

  h2 = table_list[0].render()

  print(h2 == h1)
```

Comment: Regarding my last comment, it seems to be because the generated CSS differs before and after I call `display` on an individual table. My current workaround is to add a `clear_output(wait=True)` after each individual display before generating the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer, but some information still. I can't reproduce the issue, I have the desired output already. Maybe due to some package versions? Using pandas 1.0.3 and IPython 7.13.0 here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For posteriry, I'm posting my solution to the problem:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML, clear_output

# source https://github.com/epmoyer/ipy_table/issues/24

def display_multi_table(table_list):
  for t in table_list:
    display(t)
    clear_output(wait=True)

  html = HTML('<table><tr style="background-color:white;">' + ''.join([
      '<td style="black;height:500px;width:600px">' + table.render() + '</td>'
      for table in table_list
  ]) + '</tr></table>')
  return html
```

I'm not sure why I need to make use of `clear_output`, but it worked...